# Join two dataframes. Add a column value if index value of first matches the second

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, call them 1st and 2nd.
1st has index - 'customer'. 2nd also has index - 'customer' with some similar and some different values.
1st has columns 'P' and 'Q'. 2nd also has columns by the name 'P' and 'Q'.
I want to join both dataframes like, if any index value of 1st matches index value of 2nd, then add corresonding values of 'P' and 'Q' from B to 'P' and 'Q' of 1st.
Return dataframe 1st

example
1st dataframe is:

```
customer    P   Q
A         0.5   4
B         0.4   6
C         0.3   5
D         0.7   7
```

2nd dataframe is:

```
customer    P   Q
B           4   20
D           5   21
E           6   22
F           7   23
```

Output should be:

```
Customer    P   Q   
A          0.5  4   
B          4.4  26  (6+20)
C          0.3  5   
D          5.7  28  (7+21)
```

Comment: you mean `A.join(B, how='outer')`?

Comment: Outer join will give me all customer index values. I don't want values that exist in B but not in A.

Comment: so you want `A.join(B, how='left')`

Comment: This question could be improved by example data and desired output.  It's not clear if you mean "add" as in arithmetic addition or just that you want this "additional column" included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 2),
                 pd.Index(list('abc'),name='customer'),
                 list('PQ'))
B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 2),
                 pd.Index(list('bcd'),name='customer'),
                 list('PQ'))

A
```

[image]

```
B
```

[image]

```
(A + B).dropna()
```

[image]

#### Solution

IIUC you want to add to `A`, the values of `B` where `B` has a common index, otherwise just take values of `A`.

```
A.add(B, fill_value=0).reindex_like(A)
```

[image]